# WinUI3, Disabled TreeView doesn't render items with disabled color brush? Why not?

Tags: windows, xaml, treeview, winui-3, winui

I have been experimenting with the WinUI3 Gallery app.
In XAML, I set the IsEnabled property of a TreeView to False.
For example I add `IsEnabled="False"` to the xaml here:
https://github.com/microsoft/WinUI-Gallery/blob/1d61342cd0a646d8d56758048315b34ef42864bf/WinUIGallery/ControlPages/TreeViewPage.xaml#L46

and my expectation is that the `TreeViewItem`s would render themselves using the `TreeViewItemForegroundDisbled` brush defined here:
https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/8390ab44f93e643434059d45aefb29b2f7070a87/dev/TreeView/TreeView_themeresources.xaml#L22

The TreeView control does indeed become disabled, in that it doesn't respond to mouse or keyboard. But the rendering of the `TreeViewItem`s doesn't change. The visual appearance stays the same, which is misleading/confusing to the user in my opinion. I'd like it to appear disabled as other controls like TextBox, Button, etc do when they are disabled.

As an act of desperation, I also tried binding the TreeViewItem's `IsEnabled` property to the parent `TreeView`'s `IsEnabled` property, something like this:

```
        <TreeView x:Name="treeNodes" Grid.Column="0" Margin="8" 
                  IsEnabled="False"
                  ItemsSource="{x:Bind RootNodes}" SelectedItem ="{x:Bind SelectedNode, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="vm:ConfigNodeVM">
                    <TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{x:Bind Children}" Content="{x:Bind Name}" 
                                  IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=treeNodes, Path=IsEnabled, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>
```

but that didn't work either.

Why are the `TreeNodeItem`s not rendering with the 'Disabled' state?
What can I do to make them render in the Disabled state when the `TreeView`'s `IsEnabled="False"`?

(and, for bonus points, what could I have read in the WinUI source at microsoft-ui-xaml repo that would make me understand why the disabled brush isn't used like I would expect it to be?)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this an issue with the TreeView control. When setting the TreeViewItem's `IsEnabled` to `false`, the VisualStates do not get updated properly. As a workaround, you can either call `VisualStateManger.GoToState(item, "Disabled", true)` or override the template of the TreeViewItem with the following:

```xml
<Style TargetType="TreeViewItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultListViewItemStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemBackground}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemBorderBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemBorderThemeThickness}" />
    <Setter Property="GlyphBrush" Value="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemForeground}" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemMinHeight}" />
    <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="{ThemeResource ControlCornerRadius}" />
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualMargin" Value="0,-1,0,-1" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                <Grid x:Name="ContentPresenterGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Margin="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemPresenterMargin}" Padding="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemPresenterPadding}" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}">

                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Enabled" />

                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="ContentPresenterGrid.Background" Value="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                    <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                    <Setter Target="SelectionIndicator.Fill" Value="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemSelectionIndicatorForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                    <Setter Target="CollapsedGlyph.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                    <Setter Target="ExpandedGlyph.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                    <Setter Target="ContentPresenterGrid.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemBorderBrushPointerOver}" />
                                    <Setter Target="SelectionIndicator.Opacity" Value="0" />

                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>

                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="ContentPresenterGrid.Background" Value="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemBackgroundPressed}" />
                                    <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemForegroundPressed}" />
                                    <Setter Target="SelectionIndicator.Fill" Value="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemSelectionIndicatorForegroundPressed}" />
                                    <Setter Target="CollapsedGlyph.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemForegroundPressed}" />
                                    <Setter Target="ExpandedGlyph.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemForegroundPressed}" />
                                    <Setter Target="ContentPresenterGrid.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemBorderBrushPressed}" />
                                    <Setter Target="SelectionIndicator.Opacity" Value="0" />

                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>

                            <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="ContentPresenterGrid.Background" Value="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemBackgroundSelected}" />
                                    <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemForegroundSelected}" />
                                    <Setter Target="SelectionIndicator.Fill" Value="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemSelectionIndicatorForeground}" />
                                    <Setter Target="CollapsedGlyph.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemForegroundSelected}" />
                                    <Setter Target="ExpandedGlyph.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemForegroundSelected}" />
                                    <Setter Target="ContentPresenterGrid.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemBorderBrushSelected}" />
                                    <Setter Target="SelectionIndicator.Opacity" Value="1" />

                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>

                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="ContentPresenterGrid.Background" Value="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemBackgroundDisabled}" />
                                    <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemForegroundDisabled}" />
                                    <Setter Target="SelectionIndicator.Fill" Value="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemSelectionIndicatorForegroundDisabled}" />
                                    <Setter Target="CollapsedGlyph.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemForegroundDisabled}" />
                                    <Setter Target="ExpandedGlyph.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemForegroundDisabled}" />
                                    <Setter Target="ContentPresenterGrid.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemBorderBrushDisabled}" />

                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>

                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOverSelected">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="ContentPresenterGrid.Background" Value="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemBackgroundSelectedPointerOver}" />
                                    <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemForegroundSelectedPointerOver}" />
                                    <Setter Target="SelectionIndicator.Fill" Value="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemSelectionIndicatorForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                    <Setter Target="CollapsedGlyph.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemForegroundSelectedPointerOver}" />
                                    <Setter Target="ExpandedGlyph.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemForegroundSelectedPointerOver}" />
                                    <Setter Target="ContentPresenterGrid.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemBorderBrushSelectedPointerOver}" />
                                    <Setter Target="SelectionIndicator.Opacity" Value="1" />

                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>

                            <VisualState x:Name="PressedSelected">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="ContentPresenterGrid.Background" Value="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemBackgroundSelectedPressed}" />
                                    <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemForegroundSelectedPressed}" />
                                    <Setter Target="SelectionIndicator.Fill" Value="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemSelectionIndicatorForegroundPressed}" />
                                    <Setter Target="CollapsedGlyph.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemForegroundSelectedPressed}" />
                                    <Setter Target="ExpandedGlyph.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemForegroundSelectedPressed}" />
                                    <Setter Target="ContentPresenterGrid.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemBorderBrushSelectedPressed}" />
                                    <Setter Target="SelectionIndicator.Opacity" Value="1" />

                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="SelectedDisabled">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="ContentPresenterGrid.Background" Value="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemBackgroundSelectedDisabled}" />
                                    <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemForegroundSelectedDisabled}" />
                                    <Setter Target="SelectionIndicator.Fill" Value="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemSelectionIndicatorForegroundDisabled}" />
                                    <Setter Target="CollapsedGlyph.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemForegroundSelectedDisabled}" />
                                    <Setter Target="ExpandedGlyph.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemForegroundSelectedDisabled}" />
                                    <Setter Target="ContentPresenterGrid.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemBorderBrushSelectedDisabled}" />
                                    <Setter Target="SelectionIndicator.Opacity" Value="1" />

                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>

                            <VisualState x:Name="ReorderedPlaceholder">

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="MultiSelectGrid" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>

                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="TreeViewMultiSelectStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="TreeViewMultiSelectDisabled" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="TreeViewMultiSelectEnabledUnselected">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="MultiSelectCheckBox.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                    <Setter Target="ExpandCollapseChevron.Padding" Value="0,0,14,0" />
                                    <Setter Target="ContentPresenterGrid.Padding" Value="0" />

                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="TreeViewMultiSelectEnabledSelected">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="MultiSelectCheckBox.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                    <Setter Target="MultiSelectGrid.Background" Value="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemBackgroundSelected}" />
                                    <Setter Target="MultiSelectGrid.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemMultiSelectBorderBrushSelected}" />
                                    <Setter Target="ExpandCollapseChevron.Padding" Value="0,0,14,0" />
                                    <Setter Target="ContentPresenterGrid.Padding" Value="0" />

                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>

                        </VisualStateGroup>

                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DragStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="NotDragging" />

                            <VisualState x:Name="MultipleDraggingPrimary">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="MultiSelectCheckBox.Opacity" Value="0" />
                                    <Setter Target="MultiArrangeOverlayTextBorder.Visibility" Value="Visible" />

                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>

                        </VisualStateGroup>

                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="SelectionIndicator" Width="3" Height="16" Fill="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemSelectionIndicatorForeground}" Opacity="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" RadiusX="2" RadiusY="2" />
                    <Grid x:Name="MultiSelectGrid" Margin="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemMultiSelectSelectedItemBorderMargin}" Padding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TreeViewItemTemplateSettings.Indentation}" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemBorderThemeThickness}" CornerRadius="{ThemeResource ControlCornerRadius}">

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                            <CheckBox x:Name="MultiSelectCheckBox" Width="32" MinWidth="32" MinHeight="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemMultiSelectCheckBoxMinHeight}" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Collapsed" IsTabStop="False" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" />
                            <Border x:Name="MultiArrangeOverlayTextBorder" Visibility="Collapsed" IsHitTestVisible="False" MinWidth="20" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundAccentBrush}" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundChromeWhiteBrush}" CornerRadius="{ThemeResource ControlCornerRadius}">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="MultiArrangeOverlayText" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TreeViewItemTemplateSettings.DragItemsCount}" Style="{ThemeResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}" Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundChromeWhiteBrush}" IsHitTestVisible="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" />
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid x:Name="ExpandCollapseChevron" Grid.Column="1" Padding="14,0" Width="Auto" Opacity="{TemplateBinding GlyphOpacity}" Background="Transparent">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="CollapsedGlyph" Foreground="{TemplateBinding GlyphBrush}" Width="12" Height="12" Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TreeViewItemTemplateSettings.CollapsedGlyphVisibility}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding GlyphSize}" Text="{TemplateBinding CollapsedGlyph}" FontFamily="{StaticResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" Padding="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" IsTextScaleFactorEnabled="False" IsHitTestVisible="False" />
                            <TextBlock x:Name="ExpandedGlyph" Foreground="{TemplateBinding GlyphBrush}" Width="12" Height="12" Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TreeViewItemTemplateSettings.ExpandedGlyphVisibility}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding GlyphSize}" Text="{TemplateBinding ExpandedGlyph}" FontFamily="{StaticResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" Padding="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" IsTextScaleFactorEnabled="False" IsHitTestVisible="False" />
                        </Grid>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" Grid.Column="2" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" MinHeight="{ThemeResource TreeViewItemContentHeight}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />

                    </Grid>

                </Grid>

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: The style override looks like a very promising solution, however I cannot get it to work with the suggestion you provided. If you  have a moment, could you provide a MWE or a little more info?

I tried this: Pasted your Style above into the Resources section of my page, and then expected my TreeViewItem on that page should use it. Apparently it does, because I get an exception when the page is initialized.

Furthermore, if I comment out the ControlTemplate portion of the style, it then runs, and I can change, for example, the Background to Red to see that it is being applied.

Comment: Ah! I think the reason it doesn't work directly from MS is that the 'disabled' visual state is applied to the ContentPresenter, which for a default TreeView is a TextBlock control, which doesn't have an IsEnabled property. If I change the <TreeViewItem.Content> to a <TextBox ... >, then it visually disables as expected when the TreeView is disabled. That's not a solution (because I want my nodes to be a simple piece of text, not a TextBox), but it is a clue about why it doesn't work.

Comment: In my testing, if you add this Style to you the Application.Resources in your App.xaml, the only thing you need to do is set IsEnabled to false on your TreeView, nothing else is needed. The reason this works is because TreeViewItem is based on ListViewItem and the ListViewItem class is need certain Visual States in the template to show the disabled state which are missing in the default template. By adding this Style with the template provided, you fix this by adding the missing Visual States.

Comment: Regarding the exception, can you tell me what exception you are getting?

Comment: I pasted the above Style xaml into App.xaml's Application.Resources.ResourceDictionary and when I show the TreeView I get the exception during InitializeComponent: 
  at WinRT.ExceptionHelpers.<ThrowExceptionForHR>g__Throw|20_0(Int32 hr)
   at ABI.Microsoft.UI.Xaml.IFrameworkElementOverridesMethods.MeasureOverride(IObjectReference _obj, Size availableSize)
   at Microsoft.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
   at Microsoft.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement.Microsoft.UI.Xaml.IFrameworkElementOverrides.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
  ...

Comment: I got no errors by pasting the Style above after "Other app resources here" comment. Still not getting the disabled look though.

Comment: Sorry that it didn't work before hand, I forgot to change one state that was crucial to this. @AndrewKeepCoding this style should work now.

Comment: @chingucoding Thanks! It did work. It also worked without the additional ``VisualStateGroups`` (FocusedStates, MultiSelectStates, SelectionIndicatorStates) and just changing the ``VisualState`` name from "Nomal" to "Enabled".

Comment: Awesome and thanks for pointing that out, @AndrewKeepCoding, I've updated my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Since `IsEnabled` works with `TextBoxes` or `CheckBoxes`, `TreeViewItem` is trying to set `IsEnabled` but as you mentioned in the comments, `TextBlock` doesn't have `IsEnabled`. So, why not creating a custom `TextBlock`, **DisableableTextBlock**? (Not sure if "Disableable" is a correct word though...)

**DisableableTextBlock.cs**

```cs
public sealed class DisableableTextBlock : Control
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(Text),
        typeof(string),
        typeof(DisableableTextBlock),
        new PropertyMetadata(default));

    public DisableableTextBlock()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(DisableableTextBlock);
        this.RegisterPropertyChangedCallback(IsEnabledProperty, OnIsEnabledPropertyChanged);
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(TextProperty);
        set => SetValue(TextProperty, value);
    }

    protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        UpdateVisualStates();
    }

    private void OnIsEnabledPropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyProperty dp)
    {
        UpdateVisualStates();
    }

    private void UpdateVisualStates()
    {
        if (IsEnabled is true)
        {
            _ = VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Normal", false);
        }
        else
        {
            _ = VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Disabled", false);
        }
    }
}
```

**Generic.xaml**

```xml
<Style TargetType="local:DisableableTextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:DisableableTextBlock">
                <Grid x:Name="RootGrid">
                    <TextBlock
                        x:Name="TextBlockControl"
                        FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"
                        FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                        FontStretch="{TemplateBinding FontStretch}"
                        FontStyle="{TemplateBinding FontStyle}"
                        FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}"
                        Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                        Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" />
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="TextBlockControl.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource WindowCaptionForegroundDisabled}" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And use it like this:

```xml
<TreeView
    x:Name="TreeViewControl"
    Grid.Row="1"
    IsEnabled="False"
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Items}"
    SelectionMode="None">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Item">
            <TreeViewItem
                x:Name="TreeViewItemControl"
                IsExpanded="True"
                ItemsSource="{x:Bind ChildItems, Mode=OneWay}">
                <local:DisableableTextBlock Text="{x:Bind Text}" />
            </TreeViewItem>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```